# Windows batch if not equal do not execute if clause

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a .bat file to execute in a windows server 2012 R2 machine. Problem is that I need to add an "if not equals" but when I try to execute it the code does not work.
I know that problem is in the if because I tried without the if and it works.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set anno=%date:~6,4%
set mese=%date:~3,2%
set giorno=%date:~0,2%

set ore=%time:~0,2%
set minuti=%time:~3,2%
set secondi=%time:~6,2%

e:
mkdir "E:\Presenze\%anno%%mese%%giorno%%ore%%minuti%%secondi%"

move \\gbjob09\Info-Bit\Sql_Ges\PRESENZE\2019\*.old "E:\Presenze\%anno%%mese%%giorno%%ore%%minuti%%secondi%"
cd "E:\Presenze\%anno%%mese%%giorno%%ore%%minuti%%secondi%"

for /f %%a in ('dir /b *.old') do (
    set originalname=%%a 
    set timbrnumber=!originalname:~4,4!
    if NOT %timbrnumber% == "0584" (
        if NOT %timbrnumber% == "0585" (
            set shortname=9!originalname:~4,4!
            echo !shortname!  
            for /f "tokens=*" %%b in (%%a) do (
                echo %%b!shortname!>> "Presenze.txt"
            )
        )
    )
)

copy "E:\Presenze\%anno%%mese%%giorno%%ore%%minuti%%secondi%\Presenze.txt" "E:\Presenze\presenze.txt"

exit
```

Like you can see the problem is only this really small part:

```
if NOT %timbrnumber% == "0584" (
```

I already tried to remove the double if but it still does not work.

I know that the old code (this one) works:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set anno=%date:~6,4%
set mese=%date:~3,2%
set giorno=%date:~0,2%

set ore=%time:~0,2%
set minuti=%time:~3,2%
set secondi=%time:~6,2%

e:
mkdir "E:\Presenze\%anno%%mese%%giorno%%ore%%minuti%%secondi%"

move \\gbjob09\Info-Bit\Sql_Ges\PRESENZE\2019\*.old "E:\Presenze\%anno%%mese%%giorno%%ore%%minuti%%secondi%"
cd "E:\Presenze\%anno%%mese%%giorno%%ore%%minuti%%secondi%"

for /f %%a in ('dir /b *.old') do (
    set originalname=%%a 
    set shortname=9!originalname:~4,4!
    echo !shortname!  
    for /f "tokens=*" %%b in (%%a) do (
        echo %%b!shortname!>> "Presenze.txt"
    )
)

copy "E:\Presenze\%anno%%mese%%giorno%%ore%%minuti%%secondi%\Presenze.txt" "E:\Presenze\presenze.txt"

exit
```

I only added a variable:

```
set timbrnumber=!originalname:~4,4!
```

that should work (it shouold get 4 characters after exclude 4 characters of the originalname variable) like shortname print 9 and 4 characters after exclude 4 characters of the originalname variable, but I'm not really sure because I don't really know windows batch (this is the first time that I use it and the original code was not mine).
After that I only need to check if timbrnumber is not "0584" and it's not "0585" but everything I tried was a fail.

Comment: Quotes go around both things being compared. I'm on mobile so I can't test if anything else is wrong, but that sticks out.

Comment: `if NOT "%timbrnumber%" == "0584" ` If you do not add the double quotes it will test `0584=="0584"` which will never match as the one has quotes and the other not.

Comment: Thanks to both, but I already tried and it does not work

Comment: ok, do me a favor before `if NOT "%timbrnumber%" == "0584"` do `echo if NOT "%timbrnumber%" == "0584" & pause` run the script and let me know the exact results `echo`ed to screen

Comment: if NOT "" == "0584"

Comment: that is what it print so maybe the problem is that timbrnumber variable

Comment: So there is your problem. Please show me firstly the exact layour of your `%date%` variable as well as `%time%`

Comment: and obviously it is `set` and used inside a codeblock.. should be `if NOT "!timbrnumber!" == "0584"` and `if NOT "!timbrnumber!" == "0585"`

Comment: For the date time part it should not be important, I'm trying it right now without the date time code part (and without the mkdir and move part). I will try it right now with the !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, as your variable is being `set` and used inside a code block and double quoting is required both sides of the `==`, this section should fix your issue:

```
if NOT "1!timbrnumber! == "10584" (
    if NOT "!1timbrnumber!" == "10585" (
```

which can be better written as:

```
if 1!timbrnumber! neq 10584 (
    if 1!timbrnumber! neq 10585 (
```

Another observation, your `time`:

```
set ore=%time:~0,2%
set minuti=%time:~3,2%
set secondi=%time:~6,2%
```

can be better created as:

```
 set mytime=%time::=%
 echo %mytime:0,6%
```

Comment: Ok I tried with if NOT "!timbrnumber! == "0584" and it print: if NOT "0585" == "0584" so it should work, but now it does not create the "Presenze.txt" file I'm not sure why since now the if should work

Comment: ok, but your second `if` loop is not met so it passes it. `if NOT !timbrnumber! == "0585"` and you just said it echoed `if NOT "0585" == "0584"` meaning your `!timbrnumber!` variable is `0585`

Comment: I would like to excecute the code only when my variable is not equals to "0584" and it is not equals to "0585" if it's equals not execute the code, Am I doing in reverse? I'm not really sure.

Comment: No that is fine, but your variabke IS currently `0585` because you said it `:)` __"k I tried with if NOT "!timbrnumber! == "0584" and it print: if NOT "0585" == "0584"__

Comment: Ok, the problem was that I put a NOT only in the echo part. My bad. Thank you a lot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193775/discussion-between-lieflayer-and-gerhard-barnard).

Comment: Huh? Your 2nd code is not equivalent to your first due to the double negative. Use either `if not !timbrnumber! equ 0584` or `if !timbrnumber! neq 0584`. Also you should not do numeric comparisons with numbers prefixed by 0 - that is interpreted as octal, which can lead to the wrong result if one side is 0 prefixed and the other is not. Also the command will completely fail if you have an 8 or 9 digit.

Comment: @dbenham yeah, thanks, you're right. I never removed `not`. I did consider octal, but it is not valid here so did not bother, but let me update regardless.

Comment: @LiefLayer please see important update on the answer, I never removed `not` in the second example where I used `neq`